# How can I intercept browser requests through an application?

Tags: http-proxy

I want to write an HTTP proxy server, but i can't seem to find out how to forward the browser requests to my application.

Comment: You're asking how to set a proxy server address in a browser. Google or other search engines can reveal this information very easily. EG: for I.E http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/change-internet-explorer-proxy-server-settings#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I see, I thought there was i programmatic way to intercept it. My mistake.